# generate default host triplet

Tags: cross-platform, cross-compiling, autotools

How can I retrieve the host triplet of the system I'm compiling on?

The question is very clear and doesn't need to be more wordish, but SO insists in imposing a question length limit. Sorry for this buzz.

Comment: run the `config.guess` script.

Comment: thanks, works. Why not post it as an asnwer?

Comment: The *"host triplet of the system I'm compiling on"* is a bit misleading or confusing because it conflates two parameters. The machine you are compiling on is called the ***build*** machine, like your desktop. The machine your package will run on is called the ***host*** machine, like your Android phone. The statement *"host triplet of the system I'm compiling on"* conflates two separate parameters. Also see [14.1 Specifying target triplets](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html) in the Autoconf docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brett suggested (dunno why he doesn't posts it as an answer), the `config.guess` script of `autotools` does that.